# How to configure DevForce to use Windows Authentication in a SL App

Tags: devforce

There is a number of different elements required in order to get Windows Authentication working properly in a DevForce Silverlight App.

What exactly are they? (I am going to answer my own question here, now that I have it working.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In web.config, all of the following are necessary:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <httpRuntime  targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Next, this class is required on the server:

```
public class ServiceEvents : IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Server.ServiceHostEvents
{
   public override void OnEndpointCreated(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
   {
    base.OnEndpointCreated(endpoint);

    if (endpoint.Binding is CustomBinding)
    {
        var binding = endpoint.Binding as CustomBinding;
        var elements = binding.CreateBindingElements();

        var tbe = elements.Find<TransportBindingElement>();
        var httpbe = tbe as HttpTransportBindingElement;
        httpbe.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
        endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);
    }
}
```

}

And finally, in Visual Studio:

1. Select the Web Project.
2. Open the Properties Window.
3. Set Anonymous Auth to 'Disabled'
4. Set Windows Auth to 'Enabled'

Now in a custom IEntityLoginManager, you can use the following to get the Domain username:

```
var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

You can then use userName to look up roles/permissions for the user.

And finally, the Windows Authentication Feature must be enabled in IIS.  This is turned on/off from Control Panel/Programs and Features/Turn Windows Features on or off/World Wide Web Services/Security/Windows Authentication.

If any of the above steps are missing, userName will be null.